# youtube preg_replace link different

Tags: youtube, preg-replace

i made this code to preg_replace the youtube code, but i got a problem, here is my code

```
// replace video Youtube to thumbnail       
$string     = array('http://youtube.com/watch?v=slBEtqC_JsI', 'https://youtu.be/bOxza0rLv1o');
//fix the '/' in the end of url
$string = trim($string, '/');
$search = array();
$search[0] = '~(?:https://(?:www\.)?youtube\.com\/watch\?v=)?([a-zA-Z0-9_\-+?:]+)~';
$search[1] = '~(?:https://(?:www\.)?youtu\.be\/)?([a-zA-Z0-9_\-+?:]+)~';
$replace = array();
$replace[1]    = 'https://i.ytimg.com/vi/$1/hqdefault.jpg';   
$replace[0]   = 'https://i.ytimg.com/vi/$1/hqdefault.jpg'; 
$soc_youtube = preg_replace($search,$replace,$string);
```

the code doesn't change the string, the output will be

```
https://i.ytimg.com/vi/https:/hqdefault.jpg//https://i.ytimg.com/vi/i/hqdefault.jpg.https://i.ytimg.com/vi/ytimg/hqdefault.jpg.https://i.ytimg.com/vi/com/hqdefault.jpg/https://i.ytimg.com/vi/vi/hqdefault.jpg/https://i.ytimg.com/vi/https:/hqdefault.jpg/https://i.ytimg.com/vi/hqdefault/hqdefault.jpg.https://i.ytimg.com/vi/jpg/hqdefault.jpg//https://i.ytimg.com/vi/https:/hqdefault.jpg//https://i.ytimg.com/vi/i/hqdefault.jpg.https://i.ytimg.com/vi/ytimg/hqdefault.jpg.https://i.ytimg.com/vi/com/hqdefault.jpg/https://i.ytimg.com/vi/vi/hqdefault.jpg/https://i.ytimg.com/vi/youtu/hqdefault.jpg/https://i.ytimg.com/vi/hqdefault/hqdefault.jpg.https://i.ytimg.com/vi/jpg/hqdefault.jpg.https://i.ytimg.com/vi/https:/hqdefault.jpg//https://i.ytimg.com/vi/i/hqdefault.jpg.https://i.ytimg.com/vi/ytimg/hqdefault.jpg.https://i.ytimg.com/vi/com/hqdefault.jpg/https://i.ytimg.com/vi/vi/hqdefault.jpg/https://i.ytimg.com/vi/be/hqdefault.jpg/https://i.ytimg.com/vi/hqdefault/hqdefault.jpg.https://i.ytimg.com/vi/jpg/hqdefault.jpg/https://i.ytimg.com/vi/https:/hqdefault.jpg//https://i.ytimg.com/vi/i/hqdefault.jpg.https://i.ytimg.com/vi/ytimg/hqdefault.jpg.https://i.ytimg.com/vi/com/hqdefault.jpg/https://i.ytimg.com/vi/vi/hqdefault.jpg/https://i.ytimg.com/vi/bOxza0rLv1o/hqdefault.jpg/https://i.ytimg.com/vi/hqdefault/hqdefault.jpg.https://i.ytimg.com/vi/jpg/hqdefault.jpg);
```

anyone can help me with this?
thanks for your help

Comment: See [this demo](https://ideone.com/zUcra2).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
'~(?:https?://(?:www\.)?youtu(?:be\.com/watch\?v=|\.be/))?([a-zA-Z0-9_\-+?:]+)/?~'
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/KdnjOF/1/). Pattern details:

- `(?:` - start of the 1st alternation group:

  - `https?://(?:www\.)?youtu` - `https://` or `https://`, then an optional `www.` substring and then `youtu` substring
  - `(?:`  - start of the 2nd alternation group:

    - `be\.com/watch\?v=` - `be.com/watch?v=` substring
    - `|`  - or
    - `\.be/` - `.be/` substring
  - `)` - end of the 2nd alternation group
- `)?` - 1 or 0 times
- `([a-zA-Z0-9_\-+?:]+)` - Group 1: one or more word, `-`, `+`, `?` or `:` chars
- `/?` - an optional `/`

See the [PHP demo online](https://ideone.com/zUcra2):

```
$string = array('http://youtube.com/watch?v=slBEtqC_JsI', 'https://youtu.be/bOxza0rLv1o', 'http://youtube.com/watch?v=slBEtqC_JSJ/');
$search = '~(?:https?://(?:www\.)?youtu(?:be\.com/watch\?v=|\.be/))?([a-zA-Z0-9_+?:-]+)/?~';
$replace = 'https://i.ytimg.com/vi/$1/hqdefault.jpg';   
$soc_youtube = preg_replace($search,$replace,$string);
print_r($soc_youtube);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => https://i.ytimg.com/vi/slBEtqC_JsI/hqdefault.jpg
    [1] => https://i.ytimg.com/vi/bOxza0rLv1o/hqdefault.jpg
    [2] => https://i.ytimg.com/vi/slBEtqC_JSJ/hqdefault.jpg
)
```